# Pycharm search files with same name

Tags: search, ide, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

When I double press `Shift` I can write a part of a filename and Pycharm suggests which files match. However in Django framework there a lot of files with the same name (e.g. `views.py`). Is there a way to search for a file by multiple words which match not only the filename but the path of the file?

For example if there are 2 apps - `app1` and `app2` and they both have `views.py`, and if I write "app views" then both files should be suggested. And if I write "app1 views" only the file from `app1` should be suggested.

Is there such an action or a configuration option in Pycharm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just type `app1/views.py` or `app2/views.py`, only the correct `views.py` will be shown. It even works for partial matches - `1/iews.py` will do a partial match and still show the correct thing.